# What would happen to the plateau in QHE under gradual heating ?

Tags: phase-transition, quantum-hall-effect

In quantum Hall effect (QHE), the plateau observed in $R_H$ (Hall resistance) appearing precisely at multiples of $e^2/h$ is a characteristic feature. It can be observed only at low temperatures. My question is, what would happen to these plateau if the systems is heated gradually ? I imagine the plateau will disappear finally and the classical $R_H \sim B/ne$ may be recovered. Is there any experiments on this ? Is the recovery sharp or just a crossover ? Is there any scaling phenomena, say, quantities dependent on $k_BT/\hbar\omega_c$, with $T=$temperature, $\omega_c=$cyclotron frequency ?

Comment: http://arxiv.org/ftp/cond-mat/papers/0702/0702408.pdf

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for. I want to know how the plateau would evolve as temperature was raised.

Comment: Which is why I didn't make it an answer. :-) You also asked about $k_B T / \hbar \omega_c$ as a scaling factor which ostensibly ignores the material and is thus clearly not enough information. The authors may also know the answer to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes experiments are done on that. With increasing temperature the plateaus become smaller and smaller and finally disappear. References are here. I hope they are useful.

1. Observation of quantized hall effect and vanishing resistance at fractional Landau level occupation, H.L. Störmera,  D.C. Tsuib,  A.C. Gossarda, J.C.M. Hwanga, Volumes 117–118, Part 2, March 1983, Pages 688–690
2. "Introduction to Quantum Hall Effect"  By Keshav Narin Shrivastava, Appendix F
3. Scaling of the Quantum Hall Plateau Transition, Frank Hohls and Rolf J. Haug
4. The Quantum Hall Effect: Poincaré Seminar 2004  By Benoît Douçot, Vincent Pasquier, Vincent Rivasseau, Chapter 4

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. Could you please suggest some journal articles ?

Comment: You will see them in the references of these books and the first one is an article.